# Android: change text color dynamically in listview

Tags: android, listview, colors, textview

I have a listview in an Android application with a row.xml file for layout:

```
    String[] from = { "Field_1", "Field_2", "Field_3" };
    int[] to = { R.id.Field_1, R.id.Field_2, R.id.Field_3};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.row, from, to);
    final ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In row.xml, Field_3 is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Field_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="14sp" >
</TextView>
```

Basically, text show in TextView with ID Field_3 is red, but I want, in some cases, to make the text color green.

I tried with HTML formatting, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to dynamically change the color in array or in simpleAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own **Adapter** which behaves like you want.
Just override **getView**  method and there change color
Something like this:
**view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
view.findViewById(R.id.Field_3)** and here you can do anything

Comment: How can i create a custon adapter from SimpleAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

As @megatron answered so, you should use a custom adapter which gives you pretty much freedom. And If you want to do it in this way, you can take a look to Vogella's tutorial about ListView and Custom adapters.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown